# Why am I getting not null here?

Tags: sql-server, null

I'm getting 'not null' followed by 'null':

```
DECLARE @X Int

SELECT CASE @X
    WHEN NULL THEN 'NULL'
    ELSE 'NOT NULL'
    END

SELECT 'NULL'
WHERE @X IS NULL
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `NULL <> NULL`

In `case statement` you comparing `NULL = NULL` it failed so `NOT NULL` got selected.

Try changing you `Case statement` like this.

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN @X IS NULL THEN 'NULL'
         ELSE 'NOT NULL'
       END
```

Comment: But I can't say 'WHEN IS NULL THEN' because that doesn't work: "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IS'".

Comment: @Phillip Thats not the right syntax to equate in `case`. Check my answer

Comment: Oh, thank you. I can accept your answer in 9 minutes.

Comment: `NULL <> NULL` isn't `true` either

Comment: @MartinSmith yeah that's true but how can i explain that. May be like it cannot be compared using relational operators.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
```

before your query . Sql server by default does not support equating expressions with null

by default it comes with

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
```

while ANSI_NULLS is on you cannot use NULL = NULL Checking instead "IS NULL" has to be used